# How to get URL image in UIImagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, url, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get URL image in UIImagepickercontroller after take picture.
I used following codes in didFinishPickingMedia..

```
 NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:png];
[webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];
```

But in console print **(null)**

Can you show me ? Thanks

Comment: you can get image directly from data. Why storing in directory? And what is png in [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:png];

Comment: I think you are trying to save image in `doc dir` and then fetching it in `UIImage`. Edit your `question title`

Answer (score 2):

Image picker has two success delegate methods as follow:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo;
// This is Deprecated in ios 3.0

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

It seemed to me that you are using the first method (You didn't mentioned the method but I thought to let you know). In this case you have to change your implementation to the second method.

For accessing UIImage and storing it to some path use as follow:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    //Zoomed or scrolled image if picker.editing = YES;
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 
    // Original Image
    UIImage *OriginalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 

    // You can directly use this image but in case you want to store it some where
    NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"];
    NSLog (@"File Path = %@", filePath);

    // Get PNG data from following method
    NSData *myData =     UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    // It is better to get JPEG data because jpeg data will store the location and other related information of image.
    [myData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    // Now you can use filePath as path of your image. For retrieving the image back from the path
    UIImage *imageFromFile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: It's can set name for image?? Thanks